# MSMessage didReceive(message, conversation) not called

Tags: ios, swift, msmessage

I'm in the process of making an iMessage app and the delegate method `didReceive` isn't being called in the simulator when a message comes in.

All the other methods are being called and I'm able to pass information back and forth and update the information when messages are opened but I want to parse messages as they arrive using `didReceive` to automatically update the relevant counter without the conversation initiator having to open every reply to get the counter to update.

Do I need to set something specifically to get this method to fire or does it just not work in the simulator?

Comment: Does not work here neither. Tested with Apple sample: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/IceCreamBuilder/Introduction/Intro.html